# Check for the existence of an Azure Blob using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I currently have a TSQL function called "FileExists" that checks for the existence of a file on disk.  However, we are moving the database to Azure Db and the files to Azure Blob storage, so this function needs to be rewritten (if possible).  How can I check the Blob Storage container for a particular SubBlob and FileName combination using TSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you cannot execute direct T-SQL query to Azure Blob. Possible workaround is to use [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175046(v=sql.120).aspx) to run Powershell script which calls `Get-AzureStorageBlob` to access the blob and get data... but much more easier to do the whole task in .NET code, not in SQL.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "impossible because it's NoSQL." Blob storage uses a REST API. Are you certain that TSQL (or a CLR-based function) cannot make HTTP/REST calls?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I meant "direct T-SQL statements only". CLR user-defined function may be an another possible option, I agree. I re-formulated my answer.